# Installing test runner on Visual Studio without NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, xunit, visual-studio-test-runner

I recently installed XUnit and the XUnit VS runner (i.e. xunit.runner.visualstudio) on Visual Studio following the [documentation](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html). The installation process uses NuGet and on completion I can successfully see all tests in the MS Test Explorer.

However, if I start a new solution and reference all the required XUnit dll's, i.e., I want to use XUnit without using NuGet to install it, the tests never show up in MS Test Explorer (no problems seeing them in the ReSharper test explorer).

I think this has something to do with the XUnit test adapter that Visual Studio uses to find XUnit tests. It appears that NuGet somehow instructs Visual Studio to create the `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` folder on each build putting the necessary XUnit test adapter dll's (e.g.`xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll`) in that folder. The MS Test Explorer then uses this test adapter to find XUnit test (see [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399970/visual-studio-and-nuget-based-test-runners-adapters)).

When I attempt to use XUnit without NuGet, the `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` folder never gets created on build. Adding the folder manually with all XUnit dll's in it also doesn't work. It's almost as if i need to instruct Visual Studio to look in that folder, but I can't see any obvious way of doing that.

How do I use/install XUnit without using NuGet? Or, how do I get VS to look in the `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions' when looking for tests?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install a test runner manually, copy all the necessary dlls to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {version}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions`

Replacing `{version}` with the appropriate number.

The drawback here is that this is machine wide (maybe desirable in your case), and that you can't quite as easily replicate this setup on a build server.  You also will probably have to restart VS whenever you make changes to these files.

Comment: That worked for me. Make sure to include xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll